# Why Hindu Gods never appeared anywhere else on this Earth like America, Japan, China, African continents, Middle east before christ B. C. era?

Tags: scripture, culture

Why Hindu gods like Vishnu, siva,  and Brahma appeared for people of India in the past before christ. Why they never appeared  to anyone anywhere else on this Earth like America,  Japan,  China,  African continents,  Middle east countries before  christ B.C.  era?  People  assume that  they are made up gods by Indian people.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: Please note that the above question is not duplicate with the link which you have mentioned in the comment. My question is different hence I request you to please recheck and kindly provide proper response with the correct answer if you are able to answer. Thanks

Comment: @Kesavan: Can you please understand that my question is related to why hindu gods never appeared else where on this world other than India. Also people other than India never said or have any docs mentioning that Hindu gods born or appeared in Japan,  China,  African continents /middle east B. C. era.